# fabricjs apply filter to the image

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a programme like:

```
var filters = [
    new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale(), 
    new fabric.Image.filters.Sepia2(), 
    new fabric.Image.filters.Invert(),   
]

function grayscale(url, filter) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
    console.log(fabric)
    fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(oImg) {
        canvas.add(oImg)
    })
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject()
    obj.filters[filter] = filters[filter]
    obj.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas))
    var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
    return img
}
```

and I am calling it like:

```
var img = grayscale("some_url", 0)
console.log(img)
```

I am using fabric from cdn...

Here I am giving an image url as a parameter and filter too..

I want that image to be converted at greyscale and I get converted image as response.

Here I am getting errors like `canvas.add` is not a function.
`canvas.getActiveObject()` is not a function..

What is wrong in here ?

Need help

Comment: try appendChild instead of add like this document.body.appendChild(canvas). What is getActiveObject here? What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to convert image to grayscale using fabricjs

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the canvas with Fabirc, after you add the canvas to the document

```
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('id_canvas');
```